# 2019: a year in moderation

Tags: discusión, moderación, estadísticas

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers?
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Spanish Language over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 2 | 6 |
| Users destroyed³ | 3 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 3 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 89 | 332 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 4 | 91 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 71 | 632 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 96 | 239 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 94 | 623 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 21 | 571 |
| Tags merged | 7 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 7 | 2 |
| Tag synonyms created | 8 | 1 |
| Questions unprotected | 0 | 1 |
| Questions reopened | 7 | 4 |
| Questions protected | 1 | 35 |
| Questions migrated | 7 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 4 | 112 |
| Questions closed | 51 | 100 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 55 | 60 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 1 |
| Posts undeleted | 15 | 23 |
| Posts locked | 0 | 30 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 216 | 242 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 39 |
| Comments undeleted | 21 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 54 | 242 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 603 | 2,105 |
| Comment flags handled | 204 | 89 |
| Answers flagged | 141 | 501 |
| Answer flags handled | 472 | 166 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 14 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: [2018: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/2018-a-year-in-moderation)...
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: This data could be even more interesting if we could use it to learn something, especially since we still have in the air [Can we get the close and reopen voting thresholds lowered to 3?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3260/5481). For this reason in previous years I used to create a discussion via site retrospectives (the most recent [Retrospectiva de 2018 en Spanish.se](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3015/5481)) although barely any users, apart from the mods at that time, used to participate in them. I don't know which conclusions we can draw from those numbers.

Comment: @Diego definitely the statistic for "Questions closed" (moderators 51, community 100) speaks in favor of lowering the threshold. On the other hand, this statistic might not reflect the current situation, as for most of 2019, Spanish.SE had more than one moderator.

Comment: Can you guys answer a question for me, please? When an answer is deleted by a poster, it turns brown. Does it actually ever disappear?? I have never understood this properly with regard to SE's sites. This site does not have good explanations for this. I also have zero idea how points work. :)

Comment: @Lambie when a post is deleted, it disappears for most of the users, but it is still visible by people above a certain reputation ([now 2000 points](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)).

Comment: @Diego there is the [question close stats](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats) page which shows some numbers. I browsed through SEDE to get other metrics like average time for closing questions, and posted them in a comment to the question you are linking.

Comment: @fedorqui When I delete an answer of mine, I do not want to see it ever again. So, I think the "brown out" thing is stupid, frankly.

Comment: @Lambie questions and answers are *never* deleted, only hidden. The owner and high-rep users can see them. The reason is that, once you post something to Stack Exchange, you automatically give SE a permanent license to publish your content. You *do not have the right* to delete your posts. This is done to prevent some users from asking a question, and then deleting it when they get the answer, preventing others from benefiting from the post. This has often been discussed on Meta. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117/643262) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/643262)

Comment: @fedorqui  They can have their stupid permanent license. But why would they want to publish crap? (I am referring to some post or other of mine, not others. My crappy posts). Do you keep garbage in your house? Not deleting questions is one thing. **Deleting one's own answers to a question is another**:). These things aren't worth keeping. They don't want to deal with dvs. It's more programming for them.

Comment: FWIW, soft deletion has nothing to do with licensing; it's just safer. Everything from mis-clicks to disagreement gets easier to handle when nothing is permanently destroyed.

Comment: @Lambie writing such comment in here will not achieve much, you might want to support the [related Meta request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/answers-quickly-deleted-by-owner-should-be-permanently-deleted) . When I mentioned licensing, I was referring to cases like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339364/643262), where soft-deletion allows the community to undelete a useful post deleted by its owner.

Comment: "Destroying an user"? Wow, violent!

Comment: The table is rather hard to read, but instructive.

Comment: After comparing 2019's results with [2018 stats](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3017/1674) I think we must be happy: community is doing way more than it used to, although with the cost of being slower.