# ¿Dónde puedo consultar estadísticas sobre el stack?

Tags: soporte, estadísticas

Antes de salir de beta, el Area51 era un buen sitio donde ver estadísticas simples sobre este stack (preguntas por día y respuestas por pregunta básicamente, porque en las otras categorías siempre hemos estado bien y esas, principalmente las preguntas por día, era la que más teníamos que trabajar para salir de beta).

Ahora que [ya no somos beta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3128/5481), esas estadísticas han quedado congeladas y me pregunto dónde puede un usuario normal ver estadísticas sobre el sitio. Las [publicadas anualmente por Shog9](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3279/5481) están bien, pero se publican una vez al año y no muestran la progresión o crecimiento a lo largo del año.

¿Dónde puedo consultar estadísticas sobre el stack como el número de preguntas publicadas por día?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En https://stackexchange.com/sites puedes ver un listado de todos los sitios y obtener los datos de (y clasificar por):

- visitas al día
- número de preguntas
- número de respuestas
- preguntas por día
- % de preguntas respondidas (al menos una respuesta con puntuación positiva o bien alguna respuesta aceptada)
- número de usuarios

Además, existe el privilegio [Access to site analytics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) (el último en conseguir, actualmente al llegar a los 5000 puntos) que permite acceder a la página de estadísticas del sitio, así como la de fuentes de acceso:

- [Site Analytics](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/site-analytics): publicaciones, votos y tráfico
- [Traffic sources](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/site-analytics/traffic-sources): fuentes de acceso al sitio (directo, por buscadores o a través de otra web)

(Como moderador tenías acceso a más estadísticas, eso sí)

Si buscas algún dato más, comenta. La mayoría de cosas las ha puesto alguien en [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) (Stack Exchange Data Explorer). De lo que no tenemos datos es de los reportes (flags), así que es la parte de la publicación de Shog que no es obtenible.