# 2020: a year in moderation

Tags: discusión, moderación, estadísticas

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the past 12 months](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we welcome 2021, and in keeping with tradition, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU1Al.jpg). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Spanish Language over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 0 | 6 |
| Users destroyed³ | 8 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 16 | 287 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 1 | 91 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 15 | 930 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 14 | 395 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 58 | 657 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 7 | 386 |
| Tags merged | 3 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 7 | 3 |
| Tag synonyms created | 4 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 3 | 2 |
| Questions protected | 2 | 54 |
| Questions migrated | 2 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 1 | 51 |
| Questions closed | 30 | 96 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 33 | 20 |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 1 |
| Posts undeleted | 15 | 16 |
| Posts locked | 2 | 28 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 194 | 298 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 70 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 1 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 4 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 4 | 177 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 264 | 779 |
| Comment flags handled | 173 | 12 |
| Answers flagged | 36 | 809 |
| Answer flags handled | 428 | 413 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 1 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2019: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3279/2019-a-year-in-moderation)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/208518)

A big thank you to [Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) for writing the queries and script to facilitate fetching and posting this data to all the sites in the network, and to [Brian](https://stackexchange.com/users/459488/brian-nickel) for the subsequent work making the whole thing more user friendly.

Wishing everyone a happy 2021!

Comment: Nice that this tradition goes on! A question that came up in the comments to the answer below: when a post or a comment is deleted due to one flag raised by a moderator (e.g. a spam flag, but also any comment flag, as far as I know), does this count as a post deleted by moderators, or as a post deleted by the community?

Answer (score 4):

Comparemos los datos de los tres años en que tenemos:

- [2018: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3017/1674)
- [2019: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3279/1674)
- [2020: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4414/1674)

**M20* y C20* corresponden, respectivamente, a *moderadores el año 2020* y *comunidad el año 2020*. Lo correspondiente con *M19*, *C19*, *M18* y *C18*.

*m%* indica qué porcentaje del total lo hicieron los moderadores.

| Action | M18 | C18 | **m%** | M19 | C19 | **m%** | M20 | C20 | **m%** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 1 | 6 | **14%** | 2 | 6 | **25%** | 0 | 6 | **0%** |
| Users destroyed³ | 9 | 0 | **100%** | 3 | 0 | **100%** | 8 | 0 | **100%** |
| Users deleted | 2 | 0 | **100%** | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Users contacted | 4 | 0 | **100%** | 3 | 0 | **100%** | 0 | 0 |  |
| User suspensions lifted early | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| User banned from review | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Triage queue | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 140 | 257 | **35%** | 89 | 332 | **21%** | 16 | 287 | **5%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 19 | 56 | **25%** | 4 | 91 | **4%** | 1 | 91 | **1%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 110 | 295 | **27%** | 71 | 632 | **10%** | 15 | 930 | **2%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 107 | 165 | **39%** | 96 | 239 | **29%** | 14 | 395 | **3%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Helper queue | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 213 | 404 | **35%** | 94 | 623 | **13%** | 58 | 657 | **8%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 45 | 303 | **13%** | 21 | 571 | **4%** | 7 | 386 | **2%** |
| Tags merged | 39 | 0 | **100%** | 7 | 0 | **100%** | 3 | 0 | **100%** |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 41 | 1 | **98%** | 7 | 2 | **78%** | 7 | 3 | **70%** |
| Tag synonyms created | 41 | 0 | **100%** | 8 | 1 | **89%** | 4 | 0 | **100%** |
| Tag highlight language set | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Revisions redacted | 1 | 0 | **100%** | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Questions unprotected | 2 | 0 | **100%** | 0 | 1 | **0%** | 0 | 0 |  |
| Questions reopened | 15 | 2 | **88%** | 7 | 4 | **64%** | 3 | 2 | **60%** |
| Questions protected | 1 | 40 | **2%** | 1 | 35 | **3%** | 2 | 54 | **4%** |
| Questions migrated | 3 | 0 | **100%** | 7 | 0 | **100%** | 2 | 0 | **100%** |
| Questions merged | 1 | 0 | **100%** | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 3 | 41 | **7%** | 4 | 112 | **3%** | 1 | 51 | **2%** |
| Questions closed | 89 | 40 | **69%** | 51 | 100 | **34%** | 30 | 96 | **24%** |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 34 | 10 | **77%** | 55 | 60 | **48%** | 33 | 20 | **62%** |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 3 | **25%** | 0 | 1 | **0%** | 1 | 1 | **50%** |
| Posts undeleted | 32 | 30 | **52%** | 15 | 23 | **39%** | 15 | 16 | **48%** |
| Posts locked | 3 | 27 | **10%** | 0 | 30 | **0%** | 2 | 28 | **7%** |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 252 | 210 | **55%** | 216 | 242 | **47%** | 194 | 298 | **39%** |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 32 | **0%** | 0 | 39 | **0%** | 0 | 70 | **0%** |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | **100%** |
| Comments undeleted | 32 | 0 | **100%** | 21 | 0 | **100%** | 4 | 0 | **100%** |
| Comments flagged | 100 | 159 | **39%** | 54 | 242 | **18%** | 4 | 177 | **2%** |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 713 | 784 | **48%** | 603 | 2105 | **22%** | 264 | 779 | **25%** |
| Comment flags handled | 201 | 58 | **78%** | 204 | 89 | **70%** | 173 | 12 | **94%** |
| Bounties canceled | 3 | 0 | **100%** | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Answers flagged | 162 | 360 | **31%** | 141 | 501 | **22%** | 36 | 809 | **4%** |
| Answer flags handled | 469 | 53 | **90%** | 472 | 166 | **74%** | 428 | 413 | **51%** |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 8 | 0 | **100%** | 14 | 0 | **100%** | 1 | 0 | **100%** |

Y veamos también sumas totales y evoluciones entre años:

| Action | s18 | s19 | s20 | %18-19 | %18-20 | %19-20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 7 | 8 | 6 | **114%** | **86%** | **75%** |
| Users destroyed³ | 9 | 3 | 8 | **33%** | **89%** | **267%** |
| Users deleted | 2 | 0 | 0 | **0%** | **0%** |  |
| Users contacted | 4 | 3 | 0 | **75%** | **0%** | **0%** |
| User suspensions lifted early | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| User banned from review | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Triage queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 397 | 421 | 303 | **106%** | **76%** | **72%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 75 | 95 | 92 | **127%** | **123%** | **97%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 405 | 703 | 945 | **174%** | **233%** | **134%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 272 | 335 | 409 | **123%** | **150%** | **122%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Helper queue | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 617 | 717 | 715 | **116%** | **116%** | **100%** |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 348 | 592 | 393 | **170%** | **113%** | **66%** |
| Tags merged | 39 | 7 | 3 | **18%** | **8%** | **43%** |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 42 | 9 | 10 | **21%** | **24%** | **111%** |
| Tag synonyms created | 41 | 9 | 4 | **22%** | **10%** | **44%** |
| Tag highlight language set | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Revisions redacted | 1 | 0 | 0 | **0%** | **0%** |  |
| Questions unprotected | 2 | 1 | 0 | **50%** | **0%** | **0%** |
| Questions reopened | 17 | 11 | 5 | **65%** | **29%** | **45%** |
| Questions protected | 41 | 36 | 56 | **88%** | **137%** | **156%** |
| Questions migrated | 3 | 7 | 2 | **233%** | **67%** | **29%** |
| Questions merged | 1 | 0 | 0 | **0%** | **0%** |  |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 44 | 116 | 52 | **264%** | **118%** | **45%** |
| Questions closed | 129 | 151 | 126 | **117%** | **98%** | **83%** |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 44 | 115 | 53 | **261%** | **120%** | **46%** |
| Posts unlocked | 4 | 1 | 2 | **25%** | **50%** | **200%** |
| Posts undeleted | 62 | 38 | 31 | **61%** | **50%** | **82%** |
| Posts locked | 30 | 30 | 30 | **100%** | **100%** | **100%** |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 462 | 458 | 492 | **99%** | **106%** | **107%** |
| Posts bumped | 32 | 39 | 70 | **122%** | **219%** | **179%** |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 0 | 0 | 1 |  |  |  |
| Comments undeleted | 32 | 21 | 4 | **66%** | **13%** | **19%** |
| Comments flagged | 259 | 296 | 181 | **114%** | **70%** | **61%** |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 1497 | 2708 | 1043 | **181%** | **70%** | **39%** |
| Comment flags handled | 259 | 293 | 185 | **113%** | **71%** | **63%** |
| Bounties canceled | 3 | 0 | 0 | **0%** | **0%** |  |
| Answers flagged | 522 | 642 | 845 | **123%** | **162%** | **132%** |
| Answer flags handled | 522 | 638 | 841 | **122%** | **161%** | **132%** |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 8 | 14 | 1 | **175%** | **13%** | **7%** |

Comment: Gran trabajo de compilación! Si he entendido bien que el objetivo es que m% sea bajo, parece que estamos (estáis) mejorando con los años...

Comment: Depende. Habría que tener más datos, sobre todo en lo que respecta a cuánto se tarda en reaccionar ante las situaciones. Diego como moderador, y después como usuario de a pie, siempre ha sido muy activo en las colas de revisión y eso tenía la grandeza de que los usuarios que publicaban, especialmente los nuevos, recibieran comentarios muy rápidamente. Creo que eso redundaba en una mejor experiencia de usuario, un mejor _aterrizaje_ en el sitio. Ahora hay más revisiones, seguramente porque al no hacerlos un moderador necesita de más de una persona.

Comment: También me sorprende que haya crecido tanto el número de preguntas cerradas ([y casi ninguna se acaba reabriendo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tools/question-close-stats?daterange=last90days)), que se hayan eliminado tantas publicaciones y que haya tantos reportes de más en respuestas (esto último probablemente tenga relación con mi comentario anterior). Muchas más preguntas relanzadas ("bumped") es porque ahora hay muchas más preguntas sin respuesta ([llegamos a estar a 0](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2490/1674)). En fin, muchos datos con los que se podría debatir bastante.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, que m% sea bajo y esté bajando es consecuente con lo que ha pedido la comunidad los últimos años, por lo que gracias a los moderadores por tenerlo en cuenta y actuar en consecuencia.

Comment: hmm parece que todas las estadísticas han subido mucho de 2018 a 2019. Las estadísticas de 2018 me parecen raras. Si busco [preguntas creadas en 2018 que están cerradas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2018+closed%3A1+deleted%3Aall) me salen 101 resultados (a ti te saldrán menos porque no podrás ver las borradas). En 2019 me salen 137, y en 2020 me salen 117. Los datos de 2019 y 2020 encajan con los informes "a year in moderation", pero los de 2018 están muy lejos...

Comment: En otras palabras: entre 2018 y 2020 se crearon 355 preguntas que ahora están cerradas, pero los "a year in moderation" solo reportan 306. Está claro que en 2021 no se han cerrado 49 preguntas de los años 2018-2020. No se me ocurre ninguna explicación aparte de que haya algún error en las estadísticas de 2018...

Comment: Creo que he encontrado la razón. En el historial de revisiones de [2018: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3017/revisions) veo que, al editar el post y transformarlo en una tabla, has cambiado algunos números. En particular, "Questions closed" era (89, 40) y ahora es (19, 10)...

Comment: he arreglado los números en [2018: a year in moderation](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/2018-a-year-in-moderation) . Ahora no tengo tiempo para arreglarlos también en esta respuesta...

Comment: Datos actualizados aquí y cálculos vueltos a realizar. Gracias @wimi y disculpad la confusión.

Comment: En cuanto a los datos en sí, por ejemplo yo casi siempre que borraba un comentario como moderador lo hacía poniéndole un _flag_. Así quedaba registro del motivo por el que lo borraba (99% de los casos, por obsoleto).

Comment: He quitado las 5 últimas filas de cada tabla, porque estaban repetidas y llenas de ceros, lo que parecía un error. Puedes *rollback* si he entendido algo mal. Cuando un moderador borra un comentario usando un *flag*, ¿cuenta como "community deleted"? El número de comentarios eliminados por la comunidad en 2019 es muy alto.

Comment: @wimi está perfecto. La normalización de las tablas fue algo costosa (cambian superíndices y demás) y la hice con un spreadsheet de Google, más alguna expresión regular y un poco a pelo. Sobre el número de comentarios, hubo un usuario que al irse borró muchísimos.

Comment: Sobre _Cuando un moderador borra un comentario usando un flag, ¿cuenta como "community deleted"?_, @wimi, no lo sé.